# Why am I able to query for more than 1024 columns but I can not make a view of the same query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, view

My boss is requesting a view with greater than 1024 columns where in he will only select a few columns he wants when he queries the view so that the actual returned columns are less than 1024. Why am I able to query for greater than 1024 columns but I can not save this very same query as a view?

I am using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise

Comment: Maybe your boss doesn't want a view after all. You can accomplish this with a stored procedure, for example, that builds the `SELECT` list based on his choices.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Oh definately, I played with that idea but ran into the issue of actually presenting the result set of the stored procedure in a table format so that it can be operated on :/

Comment: We write CRUD stuff like this into user interfaces all the time, not sure what the issue might be, but ok.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Management. Non DBA people wanting to look at databases is the issue -_- appreciate the help though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A View is not a Result Set. A View is an object that needs a clear definition. A Result Set, on the other hand, has a bit more freedom. For example, you can have both missing column names and/or duplicate column names in a Result Set. But Tables and Views cannot allow for either since you would not be able to `SELECT` such columns (there would be no way to clearly specify which columns you were referring to).

Run the following, for example:

```
SELECT 1, 2 AS [t], 3 AS [t];
```

Answer (score 5):

From [`CREATE VIEW` (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms187956.aspx#Anchor_2):

> A view can have a maximum of 1,024 columns.

From [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx):

[image: Extract]

Each table can have a maximum of 1,024 columns (30,000 for wide tables).

So, the simple answer is that the (somewhat arbitrary) limits are different.